# How to use the debugger with nested static libraries in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdb, debugging, static-libraries

A project that I've inherited has the following structure:

Project A produces a static library.

Project B produces a static library and links with library A.

Project C produces the executable and links with library B.

When I run app in debug mode, I can successfully debug code within the executable (project C) and the static library from project B. I can't, however, debug anything in the Project A library -- my breakpoints are ignored. I've checked and made sure that debug symbols are enabled and not stripped. Is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may want to enable a common build folder for all your projects. That way, the dsym files will be easy to find for the debugger.

Xcode->Preferences->Building->Customized Location